# How to predict with the test dataset while using cross validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I would like to use Cross Validation for the prediction model. I would like to keep 20% of my data as a test set, and use the rest of my data to fit my model with Cross Validation.

It would like to be as following :

[image]

And as a machine learning model, I would like to use Random Forest and LightGBM.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor 
random_forest = RandomForestRegressor (n_estimators=1400, max_depth=80, max_features='sqrt',
                                   min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=5, 
                                   random_state=1, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(random_forest, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring = 'r2')
```

It gives the result, but I want to predict the y values of X_test data. Could you please help me for it? After that, I will create a model for LightGBM as well.

Comment: first create the `model`, then you can use `model.predict(x_train)` it will return a list of prdictions

Comment: @badhushamuhammed thanks for your answer but the question is how to do it?

Comment: You sound confused, and I think the root of your confusion lies in the first sentence of your post:"*I would like to use Cross Validation for the prediction model*". **Why exactly** you would like to do that? What are the objectives you are trying to achieve by using CV here? ("*Because everyone else does so*" is not of course a valid answer.) Clarifying the answer to these questions will help you in your next steps. Hope my answer below sheds some light.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the old model showed a 95% success as a result of training. But the success of predicting fell to 70%. For this reason, I aim to increase success by using Cross Validation.

Comment: Well, CV by itself does not improve performance; it just gives you a more accurate & reliable estimate of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, cross-validation (CV) is used for one of the following two reasons:

- Model tuning (i.e. hyperparameter search), in order to search for the hyperparameters that maximize the model performance; in scikit-learn, this is usually accomplished using the [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) module
- Performance assessment of a single model, where you are not interested in selecting the hyperparameters of your model; this is normally achieved with [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)

From your setting, it is clear that you are in the second case above: for whatever reason, you seem to have concluded that the hyperparameters to be used are the ones you show in the definition of your model, and, before proceeding to fit it, you want an indication of how well it performs. You have chosen to do so using `cross_val_score`, and your shown code is indeed fine up to this point.

But you have not finished: `cross_val_score` does only that, i.e. it returns a score, it does **not** return a fitted model. So, in order to actually fit your model and get predictions on your test set (assuming of course that you are satisfied by the actual score returned by `cross_val_score`), you need to proceed in doing so as:

```
random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = random_forest.predict(X_test)
```

And the procedure should be similar for LightGBM as well.

Comment: I think the root of the question is, "shouldn't we use the models generated by each fold to predict the test set?" I am also struggling with this. Should I train k models based on each fold I created and then average the results of the model for the test predictions, or is it good enough to just train a model on the entirety of the dataset as you have shown?

Comment: This stack exchange post goes into it quite well. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52274/how-to-choose-a-predictive-model-after-k-fold-cross-validation. TLDR, you don't use the models made in cross validation for your test set. It is a check to see how well your model will perform on new data.

Answer (score 1):

```
  from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
  random_forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1400, max_depth=80, max_features='sqrt',
                               min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=5, 
                               random_state=1, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)

   model = random_forest.fit(x_train, y_train)
   prediction = model.predict(x_test)
```

So the prediction is the list , then you can use this predictions to check the accuracy

Comment: there is nothing about cross validation.

Comment: You can use `cross_val_predict` instead of `cross_val_score`